# How to print two webelement in single print?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

```
WebElement firstname = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));

firstname.sendKeys("X");

WebElement lastname = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));

lastname.sendKeys("Y");

System.out.println(firstname lastname); // ???
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `WebElement.toString()` method (called by `println` method) will just print out nonsense (String representation of such WebElement

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to achieve this:

```
String firstNametoPrint = firstname.getAttribute("value");
String lastNametoPrint = lastname.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(firstNametoPrint+"\n"+lastNametoPrint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
System.out.println(firstname+"\n"+lastname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(String.format("Name %s, Surname %s",firstname, lastname));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print two WebElement you can use your code in the below format:

```
WebElement firstname = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));

firstname.sendKeys("X");

WebElement lastname = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));

lastname.sendKeys("Y");

System.out.println(firstname + "--------" + lastname);
```

However you will get only nonsense value which is of no use. Your output will be the String representation of WebElement. Can you please let me know what you are trying to achieve here so that I will be able to help you in a better way.